# Why is it possible to link against C++ Dynamic Libraries when C++ does not have a stable ABI?

Tags: c++, boost, ffi, abi

Taking Boost as an example, why am I able to link against `boost::filesystem` from my C++ program, when C++ does not have a stable ABI.

I have Boost installed in my system, and a toy program is able to link using `-lboost_filesystem`, even though `boost::filesystem` exposes a C++ API ( no extern 'C' ).

So, is it possible to create C++ shared libraries that can be linked by various compiler versions? How does Boost achieve this without "extern C"?

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main() {
    // Replace "/path/to/directory" with the path to the directory you want to list
    std::string directory_path = "/path/to/directory";

    try {
        // Check if the given path exists and is a directory
        if (fs::exists(directory_path) && fs::is_directory(directory_path)) {
            std::cout << "Listing files in directory: " << directory_path << std::endl;

            // Iterate through the files in the directory
            for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(directory_path)) {
                std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Error: Invalid directory path." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    } catch (const fs::filesystem_error& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -o fs fs.cpp -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include/boost/filesystem -I/usr/include/boost/system -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -std=c++14`

Expectation: Should get linking errors as C++ does not have a stable ABI

Got: Compilation Succeeded.

Comment: Mangling aside, how is boost able to account for the same memory layout of data structures across compiler versions/optimizations?

Comment: It's possible to link against a shared library with a "C++ API" if the library and the program are built with compilers that support compatible ABIs.    g++ and clang follow the same scheme.    While the ABI *can* change between compiler versions, it doesn't change particularly often - for a given ABI, there will be a significant number of compatible compiler versions.  It is still possible to break ABI compatibility between versions - in which case, there will need to be effort to re-establish compatibility (including rebuilding libraries and programs from source using compatible compilers).

Comment: Why do you think the ABI is not stable (in time)? It's just different on some platforms.

Comment: Whilst the c++ standard doesn't define an ABI the various platforms do define an ABI with varying levels of stability

Comment: "Expectation: Should get linking errors as C++ does not have a stable ABI": *non sequitur.* You *might* get linking errors for that reason, but you have no rational reason for *expecting* it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about ABI per se, but the real crux of linking a C++ library built by one compiler with a program compiled with another compiler would rely on both compilers sharing the same name mangling schema.

And indeed, [g++ and clang++ work the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions) and have had the same schema for years.

But as this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083064/how-to-achieve-same-name-mangling-as-of-visual-studio-for-mingw-for-c) reveal, trying to do something similar by compiling a library on Windows with MinGW and expecting it to link with Visual Studio, doesn't work.   Probably not possible unless something has changed in recent years.

Comment: Clang is a chameleon - if you use the Windows version of clang++, it matches Visual Studio.